# How to set null to a variable in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I can't find anything related to this on any question, and it is something really basic, but I can't figure it out.

So my problem is that I don't know how to set null to a variable in freemarker.
Example:

```
${hi!"bye"}          <#-- Prints "bye" because hi is undefined -->
<#assign hi="hi">    <#-- Sets a value to the var hi -->
${hi!"bye"}          <#-- Prints "hi" because hi has a value -->
<#assign hi=null>    <#-- This does not work but is what I am looking for -->
${hi!"bye"}          <#-- I want it to print "bye" because hi should be undefined -->
```

I have this problem because I iterate over a list and set a var if some logic to the specific item validates, and then check if the var exists, but if the first item creates the var, then I will have the var set for the rest of the items in the list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there's no "unassign", nor the concept of `null` exists in FreeMarker (until 2.4.0 at least, but that's far away anyway). It only have missing variables (maybe technically a `null`, maybe doesn't exist at all) and those that are there. I don't really get why is that needed in your case. Can you show a simplified example of the situation?

Comment: I needed it because I iterate over a list and I wanted to null the variable at the start of every cycle, so that then I can check if it was null or not.. I fixed it using assign == "" and then checking with ?has_content ..Thanks anyway!

Comment: So you actually need a scoped variable then. Right now for that you could call a `#function` from the loop body. There you can have `#local`-s.

Comment: Yo mean a scoped variable that the scope will be in each loop? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, except, apart from the standard "loops variables", you can't have scoped variable that belong to the loop body. You can, however, define a `#macro` (not a `#function`... that was a typo), then call it from inside the loop, and there you can have `#local`-s.

Answer (score 8):

You could assign an empty string to your variable and check with the buit-in `?has_content` if it is set:

```
${hi?has_content?then(hi, "bye")}
<#assign hi="hi">
${hi?has_content?then(hi, "bye")}
<#assign hi="">
${hi?has_content?then(hi, "bye")}
```

This will render:

```
bye
hi
bye
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you need it for, you can use a different type to indicate a "missing" value.

For instance, if you have `myVariable` that is normally a number, assign  `false` to it, and then instead of checking `myVariable??`, check `myVariable!false?is_number`. This will cover both cases (non-existent and "unset").

```
${ (myVariable!false?is_number)?c }

<#assign myVariable = 12 >
${ (myVariable!false?is_number)?c }

<#assign myVariable = false >
${ (myVariable!false?is_number)?c }
```

Result:

```
false
12
false
```

[Go try](http://try.freemarker.org/).