# Unassign plain variable in Freemarker

Tags: null, freemarker, reset, unset

In a template, using the <#assign> statement we can set the values of 'plain variable' as described in the [docs](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_var.html).  During the processing of the template, I am looking for the ability to unassign these variables.  I have been unable to find any way to do this.  Ideally setting a variable to null would be the simplest option if only Freemarker team supported this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set null to a var in freemarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190559/how-to-set-null-to-a-var-in-freemarker)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as unassign in Freemarker, but I'd try the following:

```
<#assign myVariable = aNonexistentVariable! />
```

Comment: Yes, the variable still exists, there is no way to "remove" it. But it is emty, i.e. `myVariable?has_content` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Effectively this is <#assign myVariable="" /> which is exactly what I was trying to avoid.  Any code that was doing null checks would cease to function properly.

Comment: The answer clearly states "There is no such thing as unassign in Freemarker". +1